# jquery callback headaches

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The call getData() below returns Javascript that the populateForm() method depends on..

With the alert the proper js methods from getData() are present.. Without the alert I get a js error that those methods are not present.

It works with the alert present.. FAILS without it.. I can't seem to trap it correct with a callback.. Any help is appreciated -

How can I make it work?

```
elqTracker.getData({
    key: contactLookup, 
    lookup: "<C_EmailAddress>" + getCookie('c_Email') + "</C_EmailAddress>", 
    success: function() {
        //alert('---' + getCookie('c_Email'));
        populateForm(formName);
        trackPage().done(function(guid) {
            $('#elqCustomerGUID').val(guid);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are calling getData, but not doing anything with a result that I can see.  Where does the data from the getData call go?

Comment: getData just returns javascript.. it's accessed in the populateForm() method

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about what the `getData()` call actually does, but if adding the `alert()` suddenly makes things work, then it's probably because you have an asynchronous operation that you are not correctly waiting for the completion of.  Adding the `alert()` makes it work because the asychronous call completes while the `alert()` is on screen so it eds up being done before the next line after the `alert()` executes.

There has to be something in the documentation for your `getData()` call that tells you how to successfully wait for it to be completed.  Apparently the success callback isn't enough.

If the `getData()` call is loading javascript as you said in your comment, then you may need to wait for that javascript to finish loading.  Perhaps there is a different callback to hook when that is complete.

Comment: Exactly.. I just can't seem to make that 2nd call work.. getData is an async call..  I just can't figure it out since populateForm() is in the success callback already